# Consider the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ viewed as group under addition and let $G=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ viewed as group under addition and let $G=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ where $ \mathbb{Z} \;\triangleleft \; \mathbb{Q}$

A) What is order of $\frac{3}{5}$

B) Show that G has a cyclic subgroup of order n for each $n>1$

Please help to solve this problem i really stuck

Comment: HINT: a) Look for the least positive integer $n$ such that $n\left(\frac35\right)$ is an integer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think this question is sufficiently distinct to be considered a non-duplicate

Comment: @DietrichBurde ah.  Good find.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The order of an element $q \in \Bbb Q /\Bbb Z$ is the lowest integer $n$ such that
$$
\overbrace{q + q + \cdots + q}^{n \text{ times}} = 0
$$
It helps to think of $\Bbb Q /\Bbb Z$ as the rationals "modulo $1$".

Comment: I think you meant the rationals "modulo 1", not the integers

Comment: @Alan good catch!